# how to obtain residuals from numpy svd

Tags: python, numpy, svd

I have fitted a set of points using numpy svd and have the coefficients for the fitting function.  As I understand the algorithm, it will have calculated the residuals to the points along the way and I would like to recover them but cannot see how to do this.  Any guidance as to how to get these would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There's *a lot* you're not telling us, and at least my crystal ball is a bit cloudy today. As it currently stands, this question is not really answerable. `numpy.linalg.svd` only does the matrix decomposition, you probably did something on top of that to fit something? Try expanding the question by giving details of what you actually do. SSSCE would be best.